# "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." error when deploying React/Express app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mongoose

I've created a React and node/express based app and trying to deploy it on heroku. The deployment went well and my app is available here: `https://sbansal-campaign-manager.herokuapp.com/`

However, there is a problem in calling backend apis and loading data even though the requests return 200 response. 
[image]

When I click Preview tab, however, it says: `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` which is incorrect. JS is enabled. I'm able to access the data on my local machine but not when I deploy the app on heroku. Sharing my server's configuration below:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// IMPORT MODELS
require('./models/Campaign');

const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
    `mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds145230.mlab.com:45230/sbansal-campaigns-db`
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

//IMPORT ROUTES
require('./routes/CampaignRoutes')(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  const path = require("path");
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I'm new to deploying stuff on heroku. Please help figure out the issue.
Here is the full repo: `https://github.com/saranshbansal/sbansal-campaign-manager`

Comment: https://sbansal-campaign-manager.herokuapp.com/api/campaigns is not spitting out a list of campaigns, but your site's HTML.

Comment: Yes I know but it works fine on dev machine. It could be that I might have to allow requests from all hosts but i can’t find such setting.

Comment: It's likely some sort of routing / server config issue. Your Github doesn't have a Heroku Procfile or a .htaccess in it, so I don't know how stuff's routed to your app.

Comment: @ceejayoz procfile is no longer required. heroku automatically checks the start script in our package.json and generates it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it works on your machine is because you're defining:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    ... 
}
```

When you deploy to Heroku, you're deploying the master branch and it will be running in production mode.

This code clearly states that you want to return the html page for all routes:

```
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
```

Comment: That’s not the problem i guess. https://youtu.be/eHWK4Pu6dmE  In all the tutorials this is a standard way to write in production mode.

Comment: Maybe the tutorial wants to achieve something else than you do. I can only react on what I see. Just remove and deploy without the production thing temporarily and see what happens. Go from there.

Comment: I already did and it didn’t change anything. The tutorial is doing exactly what i wanted to do.

Comment: You say it worked on your local machine. What do you think will make the difference? The only tangible difference that I can see is the production check (which makes sense for the reasons mentioned in the answer above). I'm at work and cannot look at youtube videos atm. You didn't post the code behind the imported routes that you call either. The only thing you show us is if mode is production, send back html. So what do you expect.

Comment: When you say 'already did', what did you do exactly? Did you remove the production check? Did you remove the wildcard router altogether?  Did you add some logging to see what happens when the route gets called until the response sent back? We're willing to help, but you have to provide more info instead of downgrading willful answers.

Comment: I provided the repository in the link. I even showed you the relevant code. The code behind imported routes won’t help because the issue is in the configurations. Still if you want, I can update the post. It’s okay if you’re at work, i’m at work as well, we all are infact. It would be great if you could find a solution to my problem whenever you find time because that’s what SO is all about and if you can’t that’s completely alright.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204115/discussion-between-trace-and-saran3h).

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that your index/server.js (Node App File) looks something like this:

```
// DEV and PRODCTION HANDLER
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
    const morgan = require('morgan'),
    cors = require('cors')
    app.use(morgan('dev'),
    cors({ origin: `${process.env.HOST_IP}:${process.env.CLIENT_PORT}` })
   )
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD') {
    const { resolve } = require('path')
    app.use(express.static(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist')))
    app.use('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html'))
    })
}

// WEB APP ROUTES
app.use('/api/', require('./api/Home.controller'))
app.use('/api/user/', require('./api/User.controller'))
app.use('/api/user/dashboard/', require('./api/Dashboard.controller'))
app.use('/api/chatbot', require('./api/Chatbot.controller'))
app.use('/api/transactions', require('./api/Transactions.controller'))
```

Which is completely wrong, I was also getting the same error, while doing the research I found this question and after this, I also found the official recommended way to actually use the routes, which clearly suggests that a get route should be used that to server the react files.
Here's the link to doc:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

What happening here is, that express is serving the response from //DEV and PRODUCTION HANDLER. There are 2 problems with the above-given code

1. //DEV and PRODUCTION Handler should use app.get('*') instead of the app.use('*') for serving the react HTML build file.
2. res.sendFile should be below all the other routes.

Here is also a very good blog by https://medium.com/@abdamin for deploying a MERN app: https://itnext.io/deploy-a-mongodb-expressjs-reactjs-nodejs-mern-stack-web-application-on-aws-ec2-2a0d8199a682

So finally, the correct code would look something like this:

```
// DEV and PRODCTION HANDLER
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
    const morgan = require('morgan'),
    cors = require('cors')
    app.use(morgan('dev'),
    cors({ origin: `${process.env.HOST_IP}:${process.env.CLIENT_PORT}` })
   )
}

// WEB APP ROUTES
app.use('/api/', require('./api/Home.controller'))
app.use('/api/user/', require('./api/User.controller'))
app.use('/api/user/dashboard/', require('./api/Dashboard.controller'))
app.use('/api/chatbot', require('./api/Chatbot.controller'))
app.use('/api/transactions', require('./api/Transactions.controller'))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PROD') {
    const { resolve } = require('path')
    app.use(express.static(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist')))
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html'))
    })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to enable CORS in your server-side app.

Like bellow, or create your customized:
   // Setup CORS

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');

if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {

    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');

    return res.status(200).json({});

}

next();
```

});

Comment: CORS won't solve the fact that OP's API is serving their HTML instead of an API response.